# Laravel Routes Disappeared After Installing Debugbar on Laravel 6.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Just did an installation of Laravel Debugbar on my Laravel 6.0 application, but somehow all my Laravel routes went missing after that. All pages on my site are no longer accessible, as I seem to have lost all my routes.

When I do `php artisan route:list`, I'm getting the following:

[image]

I've tried performing the following:

`composer remove barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`

`php artisan cache:clear`

`php artisan optimise`

but nothing seems to work.

All routes are still present in `routes/web.php`, and I have also removed the 'providers' and 'alias' from `config/app.php`

Appreciate if anyone can help me with this!

Comment: Are they still present in `routes/web.php`?

Comment: do you use a version control system like `git` for example?

Comment: @kerbholz Yes, all my routes are still present in web.php. I think it might be a composer problem...

Comment: @nakov Unfortunately, I'm just developing on my local system and haven't made any git commits to my code so I'm unable to rollback

Comment: Try to use `php artisan clear-compiled` or `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @kerbholz Just tried those commands, but still doesn't work. Getting the same exact routes as per my screenshot

Comment: Hmmm, isn't "Ignition" only used from Laravel 6 on? How did you install DebugBar? Edited/added anything? Does `php artisan route:clear` do anything?

Comment: @kerbholz I'm so sorry, just realized that I was running on a laravel 6.0 instead of 5.8. Didn't realise that debugbar was not compatible on 6.0, and I think that's causing the issue. Installed it via their github instructions (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar). I've tried performing that command but still it doesn't work. I didn't edit/add anything, but basically the moment I installed the debugbar, my Laravel crashes.

Comment: most of the dependancy's are not support laravel 6 you will get many problem like this try to uninstall it and wait for release updated version of debugbar